# Problem with proving the Collar Neighbourhood Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am trying to prove this particular case of the collar neighbourhood theorem. I am following the paper http://www.math.toronto.edu/vtk/1300Fall2015/lecture-nov2.pdf, but the last step is glossed over and labeled as 'easy'.

*Let $B$ be the compact boundary of a manifold $M$. Then there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $B$ in $M$ diffeomorphic to $B \times [0, 1)$.*

The proof starts from an inward-pointing vector field $V$ on the boundary, and tries to prove that its flow $F$ (sufficiently restricted) is a diffeomorphism; its inverse will then be the required map.

I have already arrived at the part where I have a finite cover $B_1, \ldots, B_n$ of $B$ so that the flow $F$ is a diffeomorphism from the sets $B_i \times \epsilon_i$ to their images $M_i$ in $M$. So the flow $F$ is a $\textit{local}$ diffeomorphism from $B \times \epsilon$ to its image in $M$, where $\epsilon$ is the minimum of the $\epsilon_i$.

The author of the quoted paper then says:

> Using compactness
>   of $∂M$ and arguing by contradiction it’s easy to see that there exists $0 <
> ε_1 < ε$ such that the flow is injective on $B \times [0, \epsilon_1)$.

I am however at a loss how to prove this exactly. Any help would be appreciated.

ATTEMPT AT PROOF:

Suppose no such $\epsilon_1$ exists. Then we can construct a sequence $b_n$ in $B$, so that $F(b_n, t_n) \in M$ with $t_n < \frac{1}{n}$ is equal to $F(b_n, t_n) = F(c_n, \tau_n)$ for some $c_n \neq b_n$, $\tau_n < \frac{1}{n}$. Said sequence has a limit point $b \in B$, as $B$ is compact. However, $F$ is locally diffeomorphic, so there exists a neighbourhood $V_b$ around $b$ on which $F$ is properly diffeomorphic.

Now magic happens, and we arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Try a proof by contradiction. Use a sequence and compactness of $B$.

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin, am I supposed to use the limit point of such a sequence? And the fact that eventually, the sequence is going to lie in a single neighbourhood? I'm still somewhat at a loss - compactness and contradiction were already given as pointers.

Comment: Yes, you contradict local injectivity of the flow in a neighborhood of the limit point.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm still stuck at which sequence I'm exactly supposed to use. I already edited my original proof to include my attempt of a proof. My main problem is that while you get a sequence of points in $B$ which get mapped to a point in $M$ which is already reached, the concurrent sequence does not need to have the same limit point in $\delta M$ (it probably does, but I don't see why...)

Comment: So, passing to subsequences if necessary, you may assume $b_n\to b$ and $c_n\to c$. But then $F(b,0) = F(c,0)$, so $b=c$. Now use the fact that $F$ is a local diffeomorphism in a neighborhood of $(b,0)$.

Comment: Ok, I totally missed the fact that $b$ had to be $c$ in my reasoning, and that's where I was stuck. Thanks a lot!